# Is there any way to consume messages from RabbitMq reading from multiple queues where one has a higher priority than the other?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, queue, priority-queue, messagebroker

I have a microservice that is processing messages of different types. One of these types(A) needs to be processed ahead of the others. So that if the queue has 1000 entries of type B and a message of type A enters the queue, then that messages is consumed before the other 1000.

We planned on using a priority queue but found that they were not supported for a Quorum type queue. We thought about reverting to using a Classic queue but we don't want to be kept from upgrading to newer versions of RabbitMq in the future.

One thought I had was to have 2 queues. One for type A messages and one for the others. Then we have a "funnel" service that would read from both preferring the A queue. This service would then move the messages to the main processing queue such that A messages would go first. The key to that would be to not overwhelm the main processing queue such that there would be thousands of messages backlogged. Is there some way to meter messages to prevent this? Or does anyone have another better idea to implement what we are trying to do?